# How to disable UITableView horizontal scroll in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, screen-rotation

Open a viewController in landscape after rotating a screen, the UITableView horizontally scrolled how to disable UITableView horizontal scroll?
I also tried using the following code

```
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: You need to rotate the tableview also :|

Comment: i set auto layout to rotate

Comment: same code paste in    

    -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation    
        {            
     self.tableViewProductChild.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableViewProductChild.frame.size.width, self.tableViewProductChild.contentSize.height);
     }

Its now worked thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same code paste in

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation    
    {            
 self.tableViewProductChild.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableViewProductChild.frame.size.width, self.tableViewProductChild.contentSize.height);
 }
```

Its now worked thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder->Utilites->Scroll view section you can disable "Shows Horizontal Scrollers" option, or in code

```
self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Comment: This is just going to hide the scrolling indicator. Its not going to disable horizontal scrolling in the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
[self.tableView reloadData];
```